# Getting Not valid license manager message in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

I try to check the availibility of my licenses in the ArcGIS Administrator, but it shows this message:

> does not have a valid license manger please enter a valid license
>   manager server

Despite the fact that the licenses server is running!

I have ArcGIS 10.3 with advanced concurrent license and both the license server and the ArcGIS installed on the same machine and the fire wall is turned off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this one is better worked through with your local Esri support.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo, they failed to solve it and they have escalated it to ESRI and its taking long time with them!.

Comment: Any help on this i am getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try one or several of the following:

- If your license server is running on your local machine replace the name of your machine with localhost (27004@localhost)
- Make sure your license is actually running on port 27004. We have it running on port 27000
- Check your firewall settings. If they block your license server port this might also be the reason.

Comment: Many thanks ragnvald, I have tried this 27004@locahost and also 27004@machine name , but it didn't work with me.

Answer (score 2):

I run the license server right on my local host and was getting this error on 10.2.2.  The only way I got around it was by replacing my hostname with the IP address.